# How can I list all (new) added files between two change sets in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

How can I list all (new) added files between two change sets in mercurial?

I can use `hg status --rev x:y` to get all changes between two revisions, but what if I only want to get the new files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg help revsets` + `hg help templates` for `hg log -r … -T …` command

```
"x::y" 
A DAG range, meaning all changesets that are descendants of x and ancestors of y,
including x and y themselves.
```

Good correct range

```
file_adds 
List of strings. Files added by this changeset
```

Keyword for template

```
>hg log -T {file_adds}\n
file3.txt file4.txt
file2.txt
file1.txt
```

(last changeset added 2 files)

```
>hg log -T "{file_adds % '{file}\n'}"
file3.txt
file4.txt
file2.txt
file1.txt
```

with just added formatting of list